# String permutation iterative improvements?

Tags: java, strings, recursion, iteration

I have written some code (below) which iterates over each character of a string and adds that character to every index of previous permutations.

For example, in case of *abc*: *b* is added to every index of `perm(a)` resulting in *ab*, *ba*.

Now *c* is added to every index of `perm(c)` resulting in *cab*, *abc*, *acb*, *cba*, *bac*, *bca*.

I use a Set, to avoid duplicates.

Please review code and how it could be improved while keeping it iterative. I am particularly looking for improvements to my existing code, rather than alternative solutions(if possible), so that I can better understand the optimization process.

There may be a faster recursive solution, but I'm currently looking to improve my iterative approach.

```
  //method called from main
Set<String> perm(String input)
{
    Set<String> perm = new HashSet<String>();
    if(input == null || input.length() == 0 || input.length() == 1)
    {
        perm.add(input);
        return perm;
    }
 //convert to char array for iteration
    char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
 //add first char as first perm
    perm.add(String.valueOf(arr[0]));

    //iterate arr and find perm for each char
    for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        perm = findPerm(String.valueOf(arr[i]), perm);
    }
    System.out.println(perm.size());
    return perm;
}

private Set<String> findPerm(String next, Set<String> perm)
{
    Set<String> perms = new HashSet<String>(perm);
 //iterate each perm to add next char            at all indexes
    for(String each : perm)
    {
        perms.addAll(addAtEachIndex(each, next));
   //remove the older perms
   //for example in case of ABC,  ab and ba should be deleted after making cab abc acb cba bca and bac
        perms.remove(each);
    }
    return perms;
}

private Set<String> addAtEachIndex(String each, String next)
{
    //ab c
    //^a^b^
    //0,0+c+0,1  0,1+c+1,1  0,1+c
//add the next char to each index of current perm
    Set<String> finalPerms = new HashSet<String>();
    finalPerms.add(each+next);
    finalPerms.add(next+each);
    for(int i=0; i<each.length(); i++)
    {
        finalPerms.add(each.substring(0,i+1) + next +each.substring(i+1, each.length()));
    }
    return finalPerms;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to code review . We only review workable codes and provide a variety of answers including alternative solutions. Asking about the complexity of your code is off-topic here

Comment: If you have multiple questions , you should try splitting the questions in different posts

Comment: Thanks. This is workable, I will remove the complexity question. By avoiding alternative solutions, I intended to get step by step optimization of the original solution (if possible). So that it can help understanding the process.

Comment: It will be nice to have some explanations on want your code does in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Descriptive naming

> ```
> Set<String> perm(String input)
> ```

I would call this

```
Set<String> permute(String input)
```

When I see `perm`, my first thought is someone making straight hair curly.  My second thought is that it might be short for permanent.  Well after that I realize that in this context, you are permuting things.  In my opinion, the extra three letters increases readability greatly.

> ```
>    Set<String> perm = new HashSet<String>();
> ```

Ignoring the confusion with naming a variable the same as the method using it, I'd go with

```
    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();
```

Now I know what's supposed to be in there.

Unless you are compiling against an old Java version, you don't need to write out `String` the second time.  The compiler will figure it out.

#### Avoid casts

> ```
>     char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
> ```

While this often helps when processing something character by character, I don't think it does so here.

> ```
>     perm.add(String.valueOf(arr[0]));
> ```

This could be

```
    permutations.add(input.substr(0, 1));
```

So rather than converting from a `String` to a character array, then getting one character, then converting that character to a `String`, we just take a single character `substr` which returns the `String` that we want.  Since a `String` is immutable, this can use the original backing array to hold the data.  The other version would likely allocate new memory because it's not obvious that it's just taking a substring.

But even better might be

```
   permutations.add("");
```

Then we can simplify the gating test to just check for `null`.  And we can put the rest of the logic in the loop.

```
    for (char current : input.toCharArray())
    {
        permutations = permute(current, permutations);
    }
```

Yes, I did change the name of `findPerm`, and I changed it to take a character rather than a `String`.  I didn't like the name `findPerm` because you aren't finding anything.  You are generating permutations.

If we change the first parameter to be a character rather than a `String`, we can use it as a character later.

The other version may be slightly more efficient, but at the cost of additional coding complexity.

And now we are processing the `String` character by character, so we convert it to a character array.  We don't need `i`, as we can work with the characters directly.

#### Don't do unnecessary work

You have

> ```
>     Set<String> perms = new HashSet<String>(perm);
> ```

and

> ```
>         perms.remove(each);
> ```

But if you change the first to

```
    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<String>();
```

Then you don't need the second line.  There is no reason to put the partial permutations in the results.

#### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

> ```
>         perms.addAll(addAtEachIndex(each, next));
> ```

So `addAtEachIndex` creates a `Set` just to return it and add to another `Set`.  Why bother?

```
        addAtEachIndex(each, next, permutations);
```

If we pass the `Set` into the method, we can add to it directly.  So we check for duplicates once, not twice.

#### Choose your datatype

> ```
>         finalPerms.add(each.substring(0,i+1) + next +each.substring(i+1, each.length()));
> ```

You are doing a lot of `String` manipulation in this section and it's not really necessary.  Consider what happens if you leave `next` as a character rather than a `String`.

```
    StringBuilder permutation = new StringBuilder(each);
    permutation.append(next);

    permutations.add(permutation.toString());
    for (int i = each.length(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        permutation.setCharAt(i, permutation.charAt(i - 1));
        permutation.setCharAt(i - 1, next);
        permutations.add(permutation.toString());
    }
```

This also works with a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String`.

Now, rather than copying two substrings and a single character `String` into a new `String`, we only copy once.  We do three character operations rather than five `String` operations.  And we can keep reusing the same `StringBuilder` as a base.

#### Summary

```
public static Set<String> permute(String input)
{
    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<String>();
    if (input == null)
    {
        permutations.add(input);
        return permutations;
    }

    permutations.add("");

    for (char current : input.toCharArray())
    {
        permutations = _permute(current, permutations);
    }

    return permutations;
}

private static Set<String> _permute(char next, Set<String> partials)
{
    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<String>();

    for (String partial : partials)
    {
        addAtEachIndex(partial, next, permutations);
    }

    return permutations;
}

private static void addAtEachIndex(String partial, char next, Set<String> permutations)
{
    StringBuilder permutation = new StringBuilder(partial);
    permutation.append(next);

    permutations.add(permutation.toString());
    for (int i = partial.length(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        permutation.setCharAt(i, permutation.charAt(i - 1));
        permutation.setCharAt(i - 1, next);
        permutations.add(permutation.toString());
    }
}
```

I also made all the methods `static` as they weren't using any object state.

#### Time complexity

If we call the outer `permute` once, we call the inner `_permute` about \$n\$ times, where \$n\$ is the length of the input.

The first time we call the inner `_permute`, it calls `addAtEachIndex` once.  The second time, once.  The third time, twice.  So on the \$i\$th time, we call it \$(i-1)!\$ times if there are no duplicate characters in the `String`.  If there are duplicate characters, we call it fewer times.

The first time that we call the inner `_permute`, each call to `addAtEachIndex` iterates 0 times.  The second time, one time.  The third time, twice.  The fourth time, six iterations.  Yep, \$(i - 1)!\$ again.

Perhaps the simplest way to think about this are that there are \$n+1\$ steps to find the permutations.  On the \$i\$th step, we generate \$(i-1)!\$ permutations.  So for a given `input` length of \$n\$, we generate \$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} i! \$ permutations.  But that's just \$\mathcal{O}(n!)\$ because it is smaller than \$ (n+1)!\$ which is \$\mathcal{O}(n!)\$.

This is as efficient as we can get asymptotically, as there are \$n!\$ results.  And we must generate each one.

Comment: nitpick: It's not strictly speaking the compiler that determines, which language features are available (though it defines the upper bound). It's the "language level". You can pass an argument to a java 8 compiler that will compile your code to run on a java 6 jvm. That excludes language features that were added since then, even though the compiler itself would support them. Aside from that: great answer